# Call state modifying function in view function

Tags: solidity, transactions, remix, contract-design

Is it somehow possible to do something like this?

```
contract Test {
    function test (bool isTransaction) public view {
        if (isTransaction) {
          foo();
        }

        ...
    }
    
    function foo () public {
        ...
    }
}
```

In the best case I would be able to call `test()` like an usual view/pure function without the need of making a transaction but if `isTransaction` is true `test()` requires me to make a transaction in order to call it. Maybe I can throw an exception or something similar to be able to compile and run this code?

**EDIT:** `bool transaction` got `bool isTransaction`

Comment: I think foo() must be pure or view, so no

Comment: I saw the answer, but I still don’t get it :/ maybe I’m messing something or u are making it complicated. For me -> if u know it is a transaction then call foo directly, if not then call a normal view function that has nothing to do with foo :/ it is always better to reduce the logic in smart contract as much as u can

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish something like this using `staticcall`:

```
contract Test {
  function test (bool transaction) public view {
    if (transaction) {
      (bool success,) = address(this).staticcall(abi.encodeWithSignature("foo()"));
      require(success, "Contract call failed");
    }
  }
    
  function foo () public {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This will compile, and `test` will execute without errors as long as `foo()` does not modify the state. If `foo()` does modify state, it will revert because `success` is `false`.

Comment: interesting didn't think about that, but where can we use such a thing or logic :/?

Comment: I´m not sure what you mean by "where can we use such a thing or logic"?

Comment: For calling `foo()` I need to make a transaction so is it possible to call `test()` making an transaction if `isTransaction` is true and if not I call `test()` like a normal view function so without needing a transaction?

Comment: I edited the question because it was not quite clear what I wanted although @Morten's answer comes closer to what I need

Comment: @Morten I mean what is the purpose of a view function that call a normal function based on a given parameter :) in other words any useful use case for that

Answer (score 1):

the answer is no. it will not compile

view functions cannot modify the state and the compiler check this
and give you back

> TypeError: Function declared as view, but this expression (potentially) modifies the state

Tested it with solidity 0.8.3

[image]